# Default variables' values vs initialization with default

Tags: java, bytecode, compiler-optimization

We all know, that according to [JLS7 p.4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) every instance variable is initialized with default value. E.g. (1):

```
public class Test {
    private Integer a;  // == null
    private int b;      // == 0
    private boolean c;  // == false
}
```

But I always thought, that such class implementation (2):

```
public class Test {
    private Integer a = null;
    private int b = 0;
    private boolean c = false;
}
```

is absolutely equal to example (1). I expected, that sophisticated Java compiler see that all these initialization values in (2) are redundant and omits them.

But suddenly for this two classes we have two different byte-code.

For example (1):

```
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return
```

For example (2):

```
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   aconst_null
   6:   putfield    #2; //Field a:Ljava/lang/Integer;
   9:   aload_0
   10:  iconst_0
   11:  putfield    #3; //Field b:I
   14:  aload_0
   15:  iconst_0
   16:  putfield    #4; //Field c:Z
   19:  return
```

**The question is:** Why? But this is so obvious thing to be optimized. What's the reason?

**UPD:** I use Java 7 1.7.0.11 x64, no special javac options

Comment: Is the result the same if you enable optimization with (if I remember correctly) `-O`?

Comment: It's `-O` (upper case), just tested though and it's not optimized away.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, they're not equivalent. Default values are assigned *immediately*, on object instantiation. The assignment in field initializers happens when the superclass constructor has been called... which means you *can* see a difference in some cases. Sample code:

```
class Superclass {
    public Superclass() {
        someMethod();
    }

    void someMethod() {}
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private int explicit = 0;
    private int implicit;

    public Subclass() {
        System.out.println("explicit: " + explicit);
        System.out.println("implicit: " + implicit);
    }

    @Override void someMethod() {
        explicit = 5;
        implicit = 5;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Subclass();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
explicit: 0
implicit: 5
```

Here you can see that the explicit field initialization "reset" the value of `explicit` back to 0 after the `Superclass` constructor finished but before the subclass constructor *body* executed. The value of `implicit` still has the value assigned within the polymorphic call to `someMethod` from the `Superclass` constructor.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: It's easy to remember when you've been bitten by it in real code ;)

Comment: Yes... in this case the compiler _should_ be able to optimize though since there is no base class to consider. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I think it would be a mistake for `javac` to perform this optimization. It's far better for the bytecode to represent the source code closely, I think. The JIT compiler might well optimize it though.

Comment: Does this apply to C# as well?

Comment: @Joachim, even if this were valid, the Java compiler pretty much never optimizes anything. That's why decompilation is so easy.

Comment: @Antonijn A quick test indicates that manual initializations with the default value at the declaration does not seem to generate initialization code in C#, but if you initialize it manually in the constructor, the code will not be optimized away and the same effect can be seen.

Comment: @Antimony: C# has different semantics again; the initializers execute *before* the superclass constructor.