# Global variables and constructor(Java)

Tags: java, oop, class, variables

When are variables at the top of the class initialized in comparison to the constructor?

Sorry, this is what I meant:

```
public class aClass {

    private int num;

    public aClass {...}
```

Comment: Do you mean static variables or member variables?

Comment: Java doesn't have global variables.  Do you mean static member variables?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Isn't a variable initialized in class scope considered global, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @AliAlamiri: Are you talking about static variables?

Comment: Aren't those called Instance Variables?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth no just normal private or public member variables?

Comment: @AliAlamiri You're talking about Instance Variables, it seems.

Comment: @John you can't have any variables declared outside of a class.

Comment: @nickecarlo yeah, aren't they considered global to their class?

Comment: @nickecarlo Outside of a top-level class. If `aClass` is an inner class, it is possible.

Comment: @AliAlamiri They're considered "global" to their own class. But they aren't truly global as actual global variables are in C. Java does not have global variables at all.

Comment: @AliAlamiri The idea of "global inside a scope" makes no sense. "global" is pretty much an antonym of "scoped". `num` in the OP's question is a regular old field, or "instance variable".

Comment: @nickecarlo Yeah that's what I thought/knew, but I thought Oli meant you can't even have instance variables "global" to the class. I was like WHAT!.

Comment: no variable out of class allowed , read  [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) basic  tutorial

Comment: @AliAlamiri I believe Oli was talking about the distinction between "global" variables (ones that are simply available in every scope in the program / compilation unit), and "globally accessible" variables. While `public static` fields (of `public` classes) are accessible from any other scope in a Java program, you still have to refer to them explicitly. (Whereas C globals are simply available everywhere using just their name.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default values (`null` for object fields, `0` etc. for primitive fields`) are technically never explicitly assigned as far as the emitted bytecode is concerned. (This is done "internally" during object instantiation, before *any* initializer/constructor code runs.)

Explicit initializer code for instance fields is "copied" at the start of every constructor, *after* a superclass constructor call (if there is any) in the class by the compiler. The code sample:

```
class Foo {
    int bar = 123;

    public Foo() {
        // ...
    }

    public Foo(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        // ...
    }
}
```

is compiled into bytecode equivalent to:

```
class Foo {
    int bar;

    public Foo() {
        this.bar = 123;
        // ...
    }

    public Foo(int bar) {
        this.bar = 123;

        this.bar = bar;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Same goes for initializer blocks. This means these variables get initialised *before* any normal constructor code executes.

Comment: I'm not sure these are exactly equivalent (at least in the general case).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663906/129570.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Right, I rephrased some of the answer and included the relevant information from that answer.

Answer (score 4):

Members defined with values are initialized in the constructor, just like any other members.  But it's not exactly the constructor you wrote; Java changes each constructor behind the scenes by inserting member initializers and initializer blocks in the beginning of it.  You could view it as the members getting initialized just before the constructor, if you want to view it temporally.

Answer (score 4):

Effectively, you can consider them initialized before your constructor gets called. So if you have:

```
class Dog {
   private String voice = "woof";

   public Dog() {
      System.out.println(voice); 
   }

}
```

You'll get "woof" printed to the console successfully, rather than `null`.